# how i batch many videos url requests in react hook and laravel

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-video

i have 25 videos i want preview it in one page, this videos url come from api, sometimes the backend crash because this requests, so can i use batch request to handle it?

also because this many requests, casting or displaying a video on a Smart TV crash the backend

Comment: Are you running **25 video tags** at the same time??? What kind of crazy page design is that? I mean not even video giants like Youtube or Netflix will go that far **on one page**. We'll discuss options in detail once you explain your page layout but options include... **(1)** If scrolling down to see each video then just have one video tag that changes (jumps) screen position as you scroll. **(2)** If doing a video-wall layout then best to have all videos edited into one (25 small pictures make one video frame). The problem here is you cannot prepare such video since _"URL comes from API"_